# How to move a row up or down in a SAS work table

Tags: sas

I have a work table in SAS and I want to move the last row of the table to 2nd last row. Is it possible doing this programmatically? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then, what do you want to do with the second last row? Delete it?

Comment: In general, SAS doesn't recommend accessing columns and rows by index. If you need index functionality, IML does provide that though. Otherwise, there are typically otherways to achieve what you need, albeit a little differently than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SET` option `POINT=` to read from specific rows based on a serial position.

```
data have;
  do row = 1 to 10;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want;
  do row_index = 1 to row_count-2, row_count, row_count-1;
    set have nobs=row_count point=row_index;
    output;
  end;
  STOP;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: You can just use one DO loop.  `do row_index = 1 to row_count-2,row_count,row_count-1;`

Comment: Good call @Tom, changed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
data class;
   set sashelp.class nobs=n;
   if _N_ = n-1 then delete;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `id` variable in your dataset, you may create one first. In the following case your dataset is called `have`:

```
data temp;
  set have;
  id + 1;
run;
```

Then, you may just subtract one from the id variable when it is equal to the max(id) and add one when it is equal to the max(id) minus one. Finally, you order your new dataset by id. This will switch the positions of the two last rows.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
case when id=max(id) then id-1 
     when id=max(id)-1 then id+1
     else id end as id,
*
from temp
order by id;
quit;
```

If your original dataset already has a variable called id, just replace all `id` in the code above for the name of a new variable, and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One more using MODIFY.

```
data class;
   _obs_+1;
   set sashelp.class;
   run;
data class;
   do point=nobs-2;
      modify class point=point nobs=nobs;
      remove;
      output;
      end;
   stop;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```